# How to upload files cross-domains with ajax?

Tags: ajax, file-upload, cross-domain

I'm uploading files from a form on foo.bar.
I'm using jquery.form.js because I don't want the browser to navigate away.

```
var ref = this;
var options ={ 
    success: onSuccess,
    beforeSubmit: onBeforeSubmit
};
$("form#file-upload).ajaxForm( options );
```

It works when the "action" attribute is set to the same domain. But I get an error if the "action" is on a different domain (e.g. api.foo.bar )

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://api.foo.bar/file/ from frame with URL http://foo.bar/index.php.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

I am aware the jquery.form plugin is creating an iframe and posting the request there.

**Is there a way to avoid the error?**

Answer (score 0):

set `dataType:"jsonp"`. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Here's more info on jsonp:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/

Comment: where shall I add dataType:"jsonp"?
please see my recent code sample. shall I add dataType to the options object?

Comment: Put it in your `options` variable.

Comment: I thought jsonp only worked for GET? Uploading a file will require POST?